# DRF Serializer Reverse Relation with link table

Tags: django-rest-framework

I would like to find all TargetedExperiments for a given Gene, filtered by the Gene.symbol.
I am still relatively new to Python and DRF, apologies if there is an obvious solution or I did not add any crucial information.

I found a lot of examples where the tables are directly linked, but none with a linking table. I tried using "through" in the Gene table, but then got in a pickle with the order of the tables.

Model

```
class Gene(models.Model):
    gene_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ensembl_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    synonyms = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'gene'

class TargetedExperiment(models.Model):
    targeted_experiment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    study = models.ForeignKey(Study, models.DO_NOTHING)
    sgrna_sequence = models.ForeignKey(SgrnaSequence, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    metric = models.ForeignKey(Metric, models.DO_NOTHING)
    sgrna_label = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    sgrna_efficiency = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0%')
    transgene = EnumField(choices=['Yes', 'No'],default='No')

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'targeted_experiment'


class TargetedExperimentGene(models.Model):
    targeted_experiment_gene_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    targeted_experiment = models.ForeignKey(TargetedExperiment, models.DO_NOTHING)
    gene = models.ForeignKey(Gene, models.DO_NOTHING)
    reported_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'targeted_experiment_gene'
```

```
class GeneViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Gene.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GeneSerializer
```

Serializer

```
class GeneSerializer(base_serializer.ObjectSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Gene
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 3
```

base_serializer (Overwrite NULL with '')

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        return {key: ('' if data[key] is None else value) for key, value in data.items()}
```

Comment: You could get all the `target_experiment` ids from the linked table and then use that.
`tg_exp_ids = TargetedExperimentGene.objects.filter(gene__symbol=<symbol>).values_list('targeted_experiment', flat=True))`, then `tg_exps = TargetedExperiment.objects.filter(id__in=tg_exp_ids)` should have all the TargetedExperiment objects related to that initial gene. There are a number of other ways to approach that though. What you did is basically implement the `ManyToManyField` with a through table but manually.

Comment: Thank you @henriquesalvaro. It is my first project in Django, and I am used to have link tables in order to resolve many-to-many relationships. Thanks to your hint I started reading more about the Django model design, and it seems there are quite a few things that I should change, including the many-to-many relationship.